# Generating dynamic image fails on certain sizes

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-resizing

I use the following code to resize an Image on the fly in this format:

```
resize.aspx?img=test.jpg&w=120&h=120
```

This will extrcat the biggest square from the source image and resize it to desired dimensions however the code fails on certain width and height e.g. when the main image is 399×399 pixel and I want to resize it to 120×120 the code fails with the following error:

> Exception Details: System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.

on this line:

> cloned = new Bitmap(tempImage).Clone(rect, tempImage.PixelFormat);

The funny thing is that the error just appears on certain values. The next value is 126*126 so it seems that rounding sizes to INT might caused the problem. But I have no idea why it should fail where there is no division by zero or negative values?

**Edit:** After all calculations, **RealRatio** is equal to **MyRatio** and on the final rectangel the values are (0,0,120,120)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true"%>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Drawing" %>
<script runat="server">
System.Drawing.Image oldImage, newImage,cloned,tempImage;
System.Drawing.Rectangle rect;
void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string strFileName = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["img"]);
    string path=Server.MapPath(strFileName);

    using (oldImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path)){

        float w=(float)Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["w"]);
        float h=(float)Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["h"]);
        if (w!=0 && h==0){h=(float)((oldImage.Height*w)/oldImage.Width);}
        if (h!=0 && w==0){w=(float)((oldImage.Width*h)/oldImage.Height);}
        
        float RealRatio=((float)oldImage.Width/(float)oldImage.Height);
        float MyRatio=((float)w/(float)h);
        float ScaledHeight=(float)((float)w/(float)oldImage.Width)*(float)oldImage.Height;
        float ScaledWidth=(float)((float)h/(float)oldImage.Height)*(float)oldImage.Width;

        if (RealRatio<MyRatio)
            {
            tempImage = new Bitmap(oldImage,new Size((int)w,(int)ScaledHeight));
            rect= new Rectangle(0,(int)((ScaledHeight-h)/2),(int)w,(int)h);
            cloned = new Bitmap(tempImage).Clone(rect, tempImage.PixelFormat);
            newImage = new Bitmap(cloned);
            }
        else
            {
            tempImage = new Bitmap(oldImage,new Size((int)ScaledWidth,(int)h));
            rect= new Rectangle((int)((ScaledWidth-w)/2),0,(int)w,(int)h);
            cloned = new Bitmap(tempImage).Clone(rect, tempImage.PixelFormat);
            newImage = new Bitmap(cloned);
            }
        cloned.Dispose();   
        
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        newImage.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        oldImage.Dispose();
        newImage.Dispose();
        oldImage = null;
        newImage = null;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are not disposing one of the images: `tempImage`. `oldImage` is disposed twice. I don't know how much difference any of that will make. Is your process 32 or 64 bit? How many requests are going on at the same time?

Comment: I have enabled 32 bit applications in IIS application pool.@Crowcoder

Comment: debug it to find out what are the values on the final rectangle

Comment: I have added the output values of Rectangel to the question. They are (0,0,120,120)@Aristos